# A table which has binding ability and also manual editing

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

What I want is to have a table having a first column with every row named by me one by one, not binding to some property. But all of the second column should be binded to a property. I cannot do these two with gridview since it only makes binding and does not let me to write something manually. On the other hand, I havent seen any flowdocument table tutorial in which someone mention binding. So what is the proper object suitable to fulfill mentioned two things?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the data you are entering? Why avoid binding to a property that starts out empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListView` and `GridView` should meet your requirements. You have the ability to set bindings on the `GridViewColumns` by using `DisplayMemberPath` or in the `CellTemplate`. You can also choose not to use bindings in a column.

Take this for example:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding NameValuePairs}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="FirstCellTemplate">
            <Grid Width="100">
                <TextBox Width="75"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource FirstCellTemplate}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
 </ListView>
```

NameValuePairs is an `ObservableCollection<NameValuePair>` and `NameValuePair` is a view model with a `Name` and `Value` properties. The first column is contains a `TextBox` on each row, the second is a `TextBlock` with the `Name`, and the third is a `TextBlock` with the `Value`.